# Initialization of class member of string-type

Tags: c++

I want to initialize string member of Test_class with "Empty string". And I don't understand why this code is wrong

```
class Test_class{
private:
    std::string string_01 ("Empty string");
};
```

and this works well

```
class Test_class{
private:
    std::string string_01 = "Empty string";
};
```

Comment: Because default member values can be specified only with `=` or `{}`. So says the standard.